# popup.html in chrome extension can't fetch news/not showing fetched news

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Code is working fine(showing css div backgrounds as well as the fetched news with javascript) as an individual html page but when using for chrome extension, in popup.html it is[image] just showing background, not the fetched news.

```js
google.load("feeds", "1");
var Container=document.getElementById("feed");
var Url="http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?";
var Limit=8;
var rssoutput="<h1>Latest NPR feeds:</h1><ul>";

function showFeed(result){
if (!result.error){
var feeds=result.feed.entries;
for (var i=0; i<feeds.length; i++)
rssoutput+="<li><a href='" + feeds[i].link + "'>" + feeds[i].title + "</a></li><br>"
rssoutput+="</ul>";
Container.innerHTML=rssoutput;
}
else
alert("Error fetching feeds!");
}

function startFeed(){
var feeder=new google.feeds.Feed(Url);
feeder.setNumEntries(Limit);
feeder.load(showFeed);
}
window.onload=function(){
startFeed()
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Exo-Black;
    src: url(Exo-Black.otf);
}@font-face {
    font-family: LobsterTwo-Regular;
    src: url(LobsterTwo-Regular.otf);
}


h1 {
font-family:LobsterTwo-Regular;
 color:#3b5998;
 margin: 25px;
}

a {
 font-family:Exo-Black;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#8b9dc3;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
 color:#3b5998;
 background-color:#c9c9ff;
}

ul {
 list-style:circle;
 margin-left:-15px; 
}



div {
 width:300px;
 height:700px;
 border: 8px solid #172631;
 background-color: #dfe3ee;
 /*
 other choices for bg-color eecbff
 */
 padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>

<link href="feedStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="feed"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js">


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing external content inside browser action popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796928/showing-external-content-inside-browser-action-popup)

Comment: @wOxxOm Solution suggested in that question is not apllicable to this one. Which is to move the js to external file.

Comment: Well, it might be not the exact duplicate so let someone else find one (actually it's supposed to be your job as per FAQ), however it seems perfectly applicable because your js code is already in a separate file and the relevant part is to add `content_security_policy` in the manifest.